# Django template not showing correctly

Tags: python, django

I got back to Django after leaving it a few months ago, and came back to that polls app I made from the tutorial. I added total votes and percentage. Percentage, as in, displaying what percentage of total votes the specific poll choice has. No error, no nothing. It just doesn't show at all. I mean, everything shows except the percentage. Like I never wrote it in the template!

results.html:

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice }} - {{ choice.percentage }} ({{ choice.votes }}) </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul><br /><br />
<p>Total votes for this poll: {{ total }} </p>
```

views.py:

```
def results(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    choices = list(p.choice_set.all())
    total_votes = sum(c.votes for c in choices)
    percentage = {}

    for choice in choices:
        vote = choice.votes
        vote_percentage = int(vote*100.0/total_votes)
        choice.percentage = vote_percentage

    return render_to_response('polls/results.html', {'poll': p, 'total': total_votes}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Help? :P

thanks

EDIT:

I tried Ignacio's solution and still no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying the choices twice. Once in the view `choices = list(p.choice_set.all())` and again in the template `{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}`. This means that your calculation will never be used. If you want to calculate the percentage in the view and access it in the template then you need to pass it in the context:

```
def results(request, poll_id):
    ...
    return render_to_response('polls/results.html', {'poll': p, 'total': total_votes, 'choices': choices}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and then access it in the template:

```
{% for choice in choices %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice }} - {{ choice.percentage }} ({{ choice.votes }}) </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Why did querying twice did this though? Weren't the values saved in choice.percentage either way?

Comment: From what I can tell percentage is not a model field and I don't see anything in the view that calls `save` on the choice model instances even if it was.

Answer (score 2):

You can't index dictionaries on a variable like that in templates. I recommend doing it the other way:

```
for choice in choices:
   ...
  choice.percentage = vote_percentage
```

...

```
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice }} - {{ choice.percentage }} ({{ choice.votes }}) </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You mean adding percentage to the model Choice? I might try that, but for future reference, how do I fix the current code?

Comment: You *can't* fix the current code. And there's no need to add `percentage` to the model.

Comment: This is a bit confusing... How does Django know what choice.percentage is? I thought it would work with the template because I read somewhere you can access dictionaries that way, but how does it work that way in views.py?

Comment: Django doesn't *care* what `choice.percentage` is. Python will know.

Comment: Try turning `choices` into a list then. `choices = list(p.choice_set.all())`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also updated question with current code, maybe I implemented your solution wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty answer:

```
# views.py
def results(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    # XXX code smell: one shouldn't have to turn a queryset into a list
    choices = list(p.choice_set.all())

    # XXX code smell: this would be better using aggregation functions
    total_votes = sum(c.votes for c in choices)

    # XXX code smell: and this too   
    for choice in choices:
       vote = choice.votes
       vote_percentage = int(vote*100.0/total_votes)
       choice.percentage = vote_percentage

  context = {
      'poll': p, 
      'total': total_votes, 
      'choices'  :choices
      }
  return render_to_response(
      'polls/results.html',
      context,
      context_instance=RequestContext(request)
      )
```

and in the template:

```
 {% for choice in choices %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice }} - {{ choice.percentage }} ({{ choice.votes }}) </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

but that's not making good use of the orm and underlying db - using annotations and aggregation functions would be way better.